# html transferring values in button click

Tags: asp.net, html, button, click

I have a html application with Textbox  and a button. (static application)

I need to transfer the textbox value on the button click,

which will take me to another asp.net application.

(Where I can retrieve that in query string) is that possible?

2 applications are  in  different servers.

Comment: Do you have some html that you can show us or a jsfiddle of what you have?

Comment: You can use `jquery .attr()` for what you might be looking for http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: To Adrew ,                                                                     <input ID="txtsrch" runat="server" style="width:700px; height:35px">                                                            <a href="doctors/index.html"> <input ID="btnsrch" type="button"value="Search" runat="server"/> </a>          This is all what i have, just a text box and a button. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the method of your form `get` and and the action of the form the url of the other website you want to hit eg

```
<form action="http://www.google.co.uk" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="test" />
</form>
```

when submitted will post to `http://www.google.co.uk?test=ValueOfInput`

**EDIT**

Just noticed you are using asp.net - this is not static html!  As your have an asp button you can add a button click event so your code looks like this:

```
<input ID="btnsrch" type="button"value="Search" runat="server" onclick="btnsrch_click" />
```

then in your corresponding cs file you can add the following function:

```
protected void btnsrch_click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://www.urltogoto.com?variable={0}", txtsrch.Text));
}
```

Comment: Thaks pete. YOur first answer is what i want, jst to use the get method.  From html page to Asp.net application. Thanks Again

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.
You can give a postback url and can get the value in request object over their.

Comment: Aniruth, if i am right, postbackurl transfers from one asp.net page to other asp.net page. right. But i want to transfer from one static html page to another asp.net page.